# Nginx reverse-proxy set up perfectly, but IPs are still 127.0.0.1?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy

The proxy works fine, my distro is Ubuntu 10.04LTS (Server) and rpaf is loaded within apache, with the following settings 
httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
  RPAFenable On
  RPAFsethostname On
  RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1
</IfModule>
```

I can be sure it is loaded, for example:

```
#a2enmod rpaf
Module rpaf already enabled
```

I had force-reloaded apache, and reloaded nginx but all my connections are still from 127.0.0.1:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2010:23:56:27 -0800] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 200 1267 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19"

Why is it still localhost from external? I'll give any info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doublecheck the requests from the proxy contain the x-forwarded-for header, usually that's the problem.

Comment: How do I check this? I think I can, but am unsure how to check between the two..

Comment: Ah, nevermind, looked at other configs and was missing the forward option completely. Will answer myself -- see other answer for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default I forgot to add the add header lines, my config now looks like so:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

And voila!